# Decent horizontal scrolling of x-axis in Coreplot

Tags: ios, core-plot

So I'm trying to get decent x-axis scrolling in Core plot.

What I've done so far is set the `globalXRange` to something large, and enabled zooming on the x-axis by stopping changes on the xaxis. Zooming works well and looks nice. I try to pan, and its terrible. It only works after I lift my finger, and its not fluid at all :( Am I missing something?

```
# pragma mark -
#pragma mark PlotSpace Delegates

- (CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector{

    return CGPointMake(proposedDisplacementVector.x, 0);
}

- (BOOL)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space shouldScaleBy:(CGFloat)interactionScale aboutPoint:(CGPoint)interactionPoint {

    return YES;
}

- (CPTPlotRange *)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willChangePlotRangeTo:(CPTPlotRange *)newRange forCoordinate:(CPTCoordinate)coordinate {

    if (coordinate == CPTCoordinateX) {
        return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:newRange.location length:newRange.length];
    } else {
        return [CPTPlotRange plotRangeWithLocation:CPTDecimalFromFloat(0.0f) length:CPTDecimalFromFloat([self getMaxValue])];
    }


    return nil;
}
```

Edit: I tried to enable     `plotSpace.allowsMomentum = YES;` but this didn't help

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using the latest (2.0) coreplot code for momentum scrolling you can have smooth scrolling and still limit scrolling to one axis only by using

```
- (CGPoint)plotSpace:(CPTPlotSpace *)space willDisplaceBy:(CGPoint)proposedDisplacementVector{

    return CGPointMake(proposedDisplacementVector.x, 0);
}
```

The `willChangePlotRangeTo` method is not needed for this task.

Note: the 2.0 coreplot branch is to be considered beta, so use this with care (and pull the branch frequently as there is constant development going on).

Comment: Oooo 2.0 is kinda out! Nice. Link? Is there a pod for it?

Comment: As I wrote, it's beta and uses an own branch. You can get the source code from Google Code. However, I'm not sure if you need 2.0 to solve this particular problem here. I just had exactly the same problem and I'm working with 2.0 so I mentioned that.

Comment: So you haven't got momentum scrolling working either?

Comment: Momentum scrolling is a work in progress. See [issue 592](https://code.google.com/p/core-plot/issues/detail?id=592) for details.

Comment: yeah this still isn't working for me...Even on 2.0. Maybe its because the parent is inside an ECSlidingViewController? Touches are conflicting between On the graph and opening the drawer/menu on the side?

Comment: Answer: yes, that's it.